# Solace CLI Output documentation

Tags: solace

Solace CLI is a powerful tool for getting state/status info on various parts of the appliance (fibre cable, network cable, power module, ADB, HBA, redundancy state, etc.)  We have problems understanding some of the info shown in the CLI output.  Does anyone know of any references/documentation on the CLI output?

Thank you.

Comment: You mean HBA, not HDB. :)

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is - http://docs.solace.com/.

I don't think there really is a directory or annex of sorts for documenting all aspects of CLI `show` commands. You would see the specific `show` commands and their output being described in deeper detail in the specific chapters where the individual topics are described and explained in greater detail. In a way, I feel that this is better for the reader to deep-dive into a topic. If you need to find something quick, the search bar is quite powerful to quickly get to the reference.

As for some of the topics you've mentioned in the question...

Redundancy for appliances:
https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Monitoring-Appliance-Redundancy.htm

Redundancy for software brokers:
https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/SW-Broker-Specific-Config/Monitoring-SW-Broker-Redundancy.htm

All things on guaranteed messaging monitoring:
https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Monitoring-Guaranteed-Messaging.htm

For some other topics, the output is sort of what you'd expect to see in a typical Linux system and is thus self-explanatory, e.g., `show interface <name>`:
https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Monitoring-Physical-Interfaces-and-IP-VRFs.htm

`show hardware details` would be similar to that of a fully expanded Device Manager in Windows or `lshw` or `lspci` in Linux. Brief description is covered in: https://docs.solace.com/Configuring-and-Managing/Montoring-Blades.htm

Just use search and ideally it shouldn't take you more than a click or two to get to what you need.